# Strapi - anonymous browsing

Tags: strapi

I'm developing a mobile app which will allow users to browse without signing up. I would like to have all my endpoints secured via token.

How would we go about allowing anonymous browsing? i.e. provide a token to anonymous users.

Comment: I'm assuming you're asking how you track an anonymous user across multiple API requests?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand your case, why do you need a token if your users aren't registered and your API opens to everyone?

The authentication system of Strapi has been built to only send token to registered users. However, the easiest way to make it work for you is to register every visitor coming in your app based on their IP or something unique as a username and set the same password for each one of them. Then, every time the user comes back, you can call the `/auth/local` URL to sign-in the user and get the token or use the token stored in the local storage.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. On our app (ecommerce app) you can purchase without registering. Hence i want to make sure that only authorised tokens can query the API's.